# Flutter + Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, flutter

HI I am Building mobile application using flutter with mysql database. Whenever new data is added in certain table of Database i want my mobile application to receive notification

Answer (score 0):

you need to use push notification whenever there is CRUD operation has been done in MySql.
you can use this package for that:- [push notification](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dropdown_alert)

```
MaterialApp(
   title: 'Dropdown Alert Demo',
   theme: ThemeData(
     visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
   ),
   builder: (context, child) => Stack(
     children: [
        child!,
        DropdownAlert()
     ],
   ),
   home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Dropdown Alert Demo'),
 );
```

Comment: i dont want to generate notification from flutter, but i want notification to receive when database is modified

Comment: So send the data to the database, then when it's already in the database, get confirmation that the files are really in the database and send a notification.